# Why isn't my tmux bind -n M-k copy-mode -u working anymore (on M1 Mac)?

Tags: tmux, key-bindings

I used to use:

```
bind -n M-k copy-mode -u
```

for quite some time now with tmux but all of a sudden after migrating to new M1 Mac it stopped working. The idea behind this binding is to immediately go to copy mode and one screen up.

Similarly `bind -n M-j sendkeys Pagedown` doesn't work anymore. Anything changed that I missed?

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 3.2a
```

**EDIT**:

It seems that something's catching my <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> as `<CTL-L=FF>` (looked up using `showkey -a`).

The binding does work when bound e.g. to `C-k`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I needed to change it to:

```
bind -n C-k copy-mode -u
bind -n -T copy-mode-vi C-j send-keys -X page-down
```

to make this work.